A colourful Colombian Sudoku
Fill the sudoku on the left so that each column, row, 3x3 box, and cells of the same color contain the numbers 1 to 9. The dots show how many numbers in the row or column of the grid on the right match the solved sudoku on the left. Good luck!


Corrected.
The answer and the puzzle are correct.

Surprisingly very tricky!
Here's the solution:

 


Step by step:
1 - First steps:

To start, we can see some of the clues on the right hand side already match, and we can mark these as bold and correct. We can now grey out any clue cell which is impossible due to row, column, box or colour:



2 - Completed clues:

Furthermore, some clue rows/columns have already been completed, such as column 8 which only has one clue correct which is the 6. So the rest of that column can be greyed out too, and the same can be applied for column 6 and row 5:



3 - Cross checking:

 We can now cross check with the real grid, and grey out and clues that are impossible due to typical sudoku rules. For instance, if there is a 1 in the left grid, any clue which has a 1 in that same row/column is also impossible. This is the same as the first step, but just applied to the real numbers that didn't match a clue:



4 - First numbers:

We have now made as much progress with what is given as possible, so now it's time for some deductions. Consider column 3. It has 4 correct clues, and 4 possible numbers left in that column, so 1 of each must be correct. This means the 3 and 5 are both correct as they are the only instances of themselves. These can be marked as correct and the grids updated as necessary.



5 - It was all yellow:

Consider the yellows. The middle is the only place a 1 can go, leaving the top left as the only place a 5 can go.

 Now considering the reds. There is only one place a 3 can go, bottom right.

This is only a small step, but sets-up for the next one:



6 - Contradiction:

Consider the 4th row, and the greys. The 3 for the greys must appear on the 4th row. If the 3 is in the middle, then the clues on the right would contradict, as there would have to be a 3 on the right as well which is impossible. So the the 3 is on the right grey in the 4th row.

Using normal sudoku rules, we can place a 3 in the top right box. This also means the purple in the bottom middle box must be 3, as it cannot be in the green, and we can fill out all the 3s:



7 - Little steps:

Going back to the 3rd row, there is not only one 8 left in the clues, so it can be placed. The 4 in the pinks must be top right as well, as the 4 in the 3rd row is elsewhere.

Now there is a 278 triple in the middle row, however in the 2nd row, a 8 must go in a turquoise cell, meaning the 8 in the middle row can be placed in the right hand pink cell.

In the bottom row, there must be a 4 in a purple cell, so some clues can also be ruled out. This leaves the 4th column with a 6 and an 8 to be placed, and as the 8 is solo it can be placed.



8 - Breakthrough

Now in the first row, 4 can only be in two cells in the middle box. This rules out one of the 4s in the bottom row, and the 4 can be placed in the purple cell in the bottom right.

In the 3rd row, there is now a 267 triple, which leaves a 9. From the 2nd row, there must be an 8 in turquoise, which means in the bottom right box, 8 must be in the 8th column.

The 9 in the bottom middle box must be in the 6th column, which means the 9s in the clues in the 5th column are incorrect.

Now we have a major breakthrough - the clues place a 7 in the bottom row. This leaves a 26 double, placing an 8 in the same box, and a 7 in the 2nd column.



9 - Dominoes:

 A 2 can be placed in the top right yellow. There is only one place for a 1 in the bottom right box, and an 8 top right. The clues in the 2nd column place a 2, and a 5 in the final column too.

The 6 in the 4th row must be the lower one, completing column 3 via row 7 too, and placing a 4. A couple of 1s can now be placed in the top right and bottom left boxes, with a 2 and an 8 after in the bottom left too, and the clues are now nearly complete:



10 - Finishing up:

The bottom left box can be finished, as can the final column, followed by the bottom right box. The middle right quickly follows, with a 6 top right. More simple sudoku deduction follow until we get to here:



The 6 in the first column isn't possible, and this allows all the clues to be completed. We can now solve from here using normal simple sudoku logic to get the answer:




Corrected.
The answer and the puzzle are correct
